# 'Shuffle' is claimed to be an invalid parameter for model_selection.train_test_split

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

So when I try to run some code featuring the line below:

```
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test=train_test_split(X_features, Y_feature, test_size=0.2, random_state=42, stratify=None, shuffle=False)
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Invalid parameters passed: {'shuffle': False}
Yet, the 'shuffle' parameter is listed on scikitlearn website (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html).
```

I tried different order for parameters, splitting X and Y separately, but that yielded no result. Is there any other way I could prevent train_test_split from randomizing the data?

Comment: what is the version of sklearn you have?

Comment: I was using 0.18.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shuffle has been introduced in 0.19, you are probably using 0.18 or older which [was following different API](http://scikit-learn.org/0.18/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html).