# sklearn train_test_split dies and shuts down python kernel

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, train-test-split

I am struggling with using the `train_test_split` function from *scikit-learn* with 3d Numpy arrays.

I have a feature array with shape (1860000, 144, 12) and a label array with shape (1860000,). In a different case `train_test_split` works well. But when I try to do split this data, my kernel shuts down. Already updated the related packages in my Conda environment

I am grateful for any advise.

Comment: Looks like this has been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31467487/memory-efficient-way-to-split-large-numpy-array-into-train-and-test

Comment: It is a memory error, see nithin posts for help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Memory efficient way to split large numpy array into train and test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31467487/memory-efficient-way-to-split-large-numpy-array-into-train-and-test)